# How to use groupingBy with reducing without getting an Optional

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping, collectors

For this greatly simplified example of my problem, I have a `Stat` object with a `year` field and three other statistics fields.  Imagine they are the yearly statistics for number of patients of each animal type from branches of a veterinarian chain, and I want to get sums for all branches by year.

In other words, from a list of `Stat` objects, I'd like to return a `Map<Integer, Stat>`, where the integer is the year, and the Stat object has the year and sums for each of the four fields.

```java
public class Stat
{
    int year;
    public int getYear() { return year; }

    long cats;
    public long getCats() { return cats; }

    long dogs;
    public long getDogs() { return dogs; }

    long pigeons;
    public long getPigeons() { return pigeons; }

    public Stat(int year, long cats, long dogs, long pigeons)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.cats = cats;
        this.dogs = dogs;
        this.pigeons = pigeons;
    }

    public Stat(Stat left, Stat right)
    {
        if (left.year != right.year)
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only allow combining for same year.");
        this.year = left.year;
        this.cats = left.cats + right.cats;
        this.dogs = left.dogs + right.dogs ;
        this.pigeons = left.pigeons + right.pigeons;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%d c=%d d=%d p=%d", year, cats, dogs, pigeons);
    }
}
@Test
public void testStat()
{
    List<Stat> items = Arrays.asList(
        new Stat(2017, 5, 8, 12),
        new Stat(2017, 123, 382, 15),
        new Stat(2018, 1, 2, 3)
        );
    Map<Integer, Optional<Stat>> result = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Stat::getYear,
            Collectors.reducing(Stat::new)
        ));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The `Optional` is unnecessary, since `groupingBy` would never create a `List` that needs `reducing` if there were no elements.

Is there a way to get `Map<Integer, Stat>`, preferably without having to create a blank "identity" object?

If I have to resort to creating an identity creation function to `reducing`, the Stat object's combining constructor has to have a year (see the constructor), so how does the identity constructor get the year passed to it?

Comment: Where would you store the ***sums for each of the four fields.*** ?

Comment: They are stored in a new instance.  See the constructor Stat(Stat left, Stat right).  It creates a new Stat by summing up the individual fields.  But I should have said three fields, since there are only dogs, cats, and pigeons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could rather achieve this using `Collectors.toMap` as :

```
Map<Integer, Stat> result = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Stat::getYear, 
                Function.identity(), (one, another) -> sumStatsOfSameYear(one, another)));
```

where `sumAttributes` is defined as

```
// stat from the same year
private static Stat sumStatsOfSameYear(Stat one, Stat another) {
    new Stat(one.getYear(), one.getCats() + another.getCats(),
            one.getDogs() + another.getDogs(), one.getPigeons() + another.getPigeons()))
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The approach of using `Collectors.toMap` is exactly right!  I was trying to make it harder than it had to be.  Note that in the example, instead of passing the function call `sumStatsOfSameYear`, it could pass just `Stat::new`.